# Interlocked*64 on WinXP 32bit

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

How should I implement these 64-bit interlocked functions on WinXP? Of course I can use full mutex, but I think it's needlessly heavyweight for this task. There must be some better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. This is much more complex than you think.

If you insist, your best bet is to use a critical section to make sure you get the barriers right.

If you really think a critical section is too heavy weight, read up on [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use CriticalSection. If you are concerned over the performance of your interlock, the solution would be to design the program so that there is less contention, not shaving off nanoseconds off the interlock operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd9bdb82%28VS.80%29.aspx) which may be simpler and faster than using a critical section.